# Change text multiple times with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

How do I change the text from an array everytime I click a button? So I have:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <a href="#" class="btn">Button 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Button 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Button 3</a>
</div>

<div class="text"></text>
```

I have an **array**:

```
var arr = ['First', 'Second', 'Third.'];

$(".btn").on('click', function (e) {
    $(".text").text(arr[0]);
});
```

How do I make it so that if I click on any of those '.btn' it will loop through the array and fade in the new text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/CtC9E/)

```
var arr = ['First', 'Second', 'Third.'];
var cnt = 0;

$(".btn").on('click', function (e) {
    //alert(arr[cnt]);
    $(".text").hide();
    $(".text").text(arr[cnt]).fadeIn(1500);
    cnt++;
    if (cnt > 2) cnt = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".btn").each(function (index) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(".text").text(arr[index]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a variable 'i' like this:

```
var i = 0;

var arr = ['First', 'Second', 'Third.'];

$(".btn").on('click', function (e) {
    $(".text").text(arr[i]);
    if (i < 2) i += 1;
    else i = 0;
});
```

Comment: `.fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
      });` He mentioned a fade in, soooo here ya go

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <a href="#" class="btn" index="0">Button 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn" index="1">Button 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn" index="2">Button 3</a>
</div>

<div class="text"></text>

var arr = ['First', 'Second', 'Third.'];

$(".btn").on('click', function (e) {
    var index = $(this).attr("index");
    $(".text").text(arr[index]);
});
```